# Starting Windows program using win32api under Win7

Tags: winapi, python-3.x

I am trying to launch an existing Windows 7 program using win32api under Python3.5. The program starts and presents a dialog (expected). Clicking on OK though results in an error "Create process failed". As stated before if I manually start the file by double-clicking the icon on the desktop and clicking OK at the dialog everything works fine.

I assume its a Windows permission issue, but unclear how to debug what the cause is. Does anyone have any suggestions. Code to launch the application is shown below:

```
import sendKeys
import time
import win32api

pathFileEPT=r"C:\Users\bartis\1234 SSS XYZ R7.0.2\XZY.exe"

# Starting the program using os.startfile or win32api results
# in same behavior
#os.startfile(pathFileEPT)
win32api.WinExec(pathFileEPT)

time.sleep(2)

# Send mouse click to ACK OK button. Note
# use of the programmatically call or manually
# clicking OK results in the same error
sendKeys.mouseClick(951,581)
```

Comment: Why not use `subprocess`?

Comment: Where is the error "Create process failed" coming from? Does it appear in a message box, in the console or somewhere else? Is that the full text of the error?

Comment: The error message comes in modal dialog box and is the complete error

Comment: The program probably needs a particular current directory.  You can check the shortcut properties to see which current directory the application is expecting.

Comment: To clarify the question (based on the OPs comments in my now-deleted answer) the `XYZ.exe` application is successfully starting, and it is this application that is presenting the error message.

Comment: Harry - Thank you for the pointer. I assume by current Directory you meant the "Start In" property? If so, how would I incorprate that into how I start my application from Python. Perform a change directory before calling WinExec?

Comment: Harry - you were correct. Adding a call to os.chdir(pathWorkingDir), where pathWorkingDir is set to the Start In value in the applications shortcut property window corrected the issue. Thank you!